# Laravel 4 - Eloquent replace null values

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a laravel web application that is nearly completed. I have had to switch database servers and have run into an unexpected problem. The new database does not allow null values. Other applications read and write to this database which is why nulls are not allowed. Therefore I will not be able to change the database. What would be the easiest way to check for null values before a save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to setup mutators in the model. even though the column name was in snake case I still had to use camel case for the function name. so SALES_ORDER_NUMBER became SalesOrderNumber. here is an example:

```
protected function getSalesOrderNumberAttribute($value) { return $this->attributes['SALES_ORDER_NUMBER']; }
protected function setSalesOrderNumberAttribute($value) { $this->attributes['SALES_ORDER_NUMBER'] = (is_null($value) ? '' : $value); }
```